# Preload WKWebView url from first VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, wkwebview

I am trying to pre-load a WKWebView before the SecondVC is called/presented.

Can this be accomplished in the swift 5 programming language? Perhaps calling layoutSubviews()?

is it possible to preload a webView before transitioning to the next view controller? OR is the only way to show this is loading is through activity indicators?

**First VC:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SecondVC.loadWebView() //PSUEDO of what I am trying to do
        
    }
```

**SecondVC:**

```
func loadWebView() {
        
        // WKWebView nit
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
     
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=\(live_client_id)&scope=read_write") else {
            return
        }
        
        
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        
    }
```

Comment: Makes no sense. There is no second view controller yet.

Comment: I know but is there a way i can preload a webview somehow before showing the next vc?

Comment: Yes, the same way you preload anything. Do it as the segue begins.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is the view controller where you have your web view. You can put the code where you load the webpage inside its initializer.

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy private var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        return webView
    }()
    
    private var url: URL!
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        self.loadWebsite()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func loadWebsite() {
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

And in the previous view controller, you instantiate the `WebViewController` prior to navigating to the web view. When you instantiate it, the initializer of the `WebViewController` is called and in turn `loadWebsite()` method which loads the web page.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let vc = WebViewController(url: URL(string: "https://stripe.com/")!)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.showWebView()
        }
    }
    
    private func showWebView() {
        navigationController?.show(vc, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

So by the time you actually show the `WebViewController`, hopefully the webpage will be already loaded.